# Cordova: How to define Plugins for all platforms?

Tags: cordova

In cordova you can add plugins for example:

```
cordova platform add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

For now i just use android platform. After i executed the above command a feature entry is generated for my platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml:

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

So im asking myself how can i define them for all platforms? In the root directory of the cordova project there is a folder named 'plugins'.
Should i push that plugins folder to my git repository too? If the plugins folder exists and i pull my git repository to my mac to add the ios platform and build it.. will all plugins be added to the ios platform config.xml automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a Cordova plugin to your project, Cordova looks into a plugin.xml file provided by the plugin you are installing.

This plugin.xml file specifies which platforms the plugin supports.

So when you add a plugin and then build your Cordova project, the plugin will be added to each platform it is compatible with. No need to do something special.

If you add later iOS platform, you will just have then to build your Cordova project and all the plugins you added to the Cordova project will be added to iOS platform too (only if they support iOS platform).